How to install StatET for R
I am trying to install StatET for R in eclipse following this instruction:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=9295
but it failed with message as following:

I have searched in the Eclipse Marketplace but there is no "StatET ECommons - Net - Core". Any suggestion to install StatET for R?
My eclipse version is:
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2024-09 (4.33.0)
Build id: 20240905-0614

That says it found the StatET Core plug-in but it depends on the org.eclipse.egit.core plugin and requires it to have a version of at least 6.8.0 but less than 7.0.0 - I believe the current egit is version 7.0.0 so it does meet that specification. A quick look at the Marketplace entry shows that it doesn't list Eclipse 2024-09 as supported, 2023-12 being the last listed.

Thank you! It works after I switching to Eclipse 2023-12.
